# How to disable the helping duck from popping up?

Tags: support, feature-request

This is a minor thing, but this duck popping up in the bottom-right corner whenever you do anything catches your attention, for nothing, this can get really annoying. Is there any way to disable it?

For now I have found two ways:

1. Go for a walk.
2. Stick a sticker in the bottom-right part of your screen (in order to hide the least area and still cover the duck I am using a duck-shaped sticker).

Also if you are reading this and hadn't noticed by now - well, sorry about that, I wish you will be able to keep not noticing.

Comment: see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308570/how-do-i-disable-quack-overflow-i-hate-this-duck-button-is-only-temporary)

Comment: A brilliant question, it  has me annoyed for past half an hour.

Comment: Just ask the duck!

Comment: Tell the duck you hate them.

Comment: Why a duck? ....

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3hjo7V7TPs

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_a_Duck%3F

Comment: @JohnMa, [if it walks like a *duck* and quacks like a *duck*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), we can safely use "it" instead of "them" when talking about *it*.

Comment: What the duck? If I answer 'no' to 'do you have a microphone?', it tells me to speak up.

Comment: @Will, https://youtu.be/Mh85R-S-dh8

Comment: @copper.hat weird, right? Then it pretends to be thinking for a while, and comes up with "quack!". This duck is the perfect troll.

Comment: After you 'speak up' with the duck, she asks whether it was helpful (I can't remember exactly) or you hate the duck. Just press "i hate you" or "i hate the duck" and it will disappear forever :). Hope that helps you.

Comment: Yes,  I wrote a comment to say that this had worked,  but it was deleted - probably by a "thanks it worked"-comment deleting duck-bot.

Comment: Adblock seems to handle it, unless it went away on its own.  You would need to manually block the duck element.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/april-fools/info  It is said that Quack.Overflow expires when it is no longer April 1 anywhere in the world.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with ["April Fools' Day"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day) click on the link.

Comment: @amWhy: Do we really need an April Fools' tag on meta?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe this could be a separate discussion, possibly [in tagging chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2018/4/2). As I have [already mentioned there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43726672#43726672), the tag with the same name exists on Meta Stack Exchange. (And it is quite likely that we could get a bunch of questions where such tag could be suitable roughly at this time of the year.)

Comment: @Martin: True. But with maaaybe one question a year, the tag will fall into misuse and get deleted every year anew. So... what's the point? :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Not at all.  It was only my mini April Fools contribution.

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308619/161676, Quack.Overflow lasts until April 3 UTC, since April 1 was a Sunday...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to make answer more accessible (so that others do not have to look in the comments).

All the details can be found in this post: [How do I disable Quack Overflow? (“I hate this duck” button is only temporary)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308570)

You have to click "I hate this duck" and after that you also have to click "Goodbye duck!"

Other possibilities are described in the linked post, but this seems to be the simplest one.

---

In case some people still haven't realized, it is probably also worth pointing out that QuackOverflow is this years [Stack Exchange April Fools prank](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/april-fools/info).

Since the whole thing [should end on April 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308618/will-quack-overflow-be-accessible-after-the-1st/308619#308619), simply waiting a bit is also a solution.